# Welcome intent creating error in dialogflow

Tags: nlp, chatbot, dialogflow-es

when I created a welcome intent in dialogflow in which "welcome" event is made.

I get error saying:"Intent with empty contexts and events '[WELCOME]' already exists".

I checked through all my intents for the error.
Previously I deleted a welcome intent is this the reason behind that error?

what can be done now?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other intent in your project that already contains the `WELCOME` event and has no context?

Comment: yeah i did search all my intents

Comment: its in just the default welcome intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WELCOME` event is a way to trigger an intent at the beginning of the interaction with the Dialogflow Agent. Although you can have multiple Welcome Intents (one for each of the supported one-click integrations), **you can only have one [Default Welcome Intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#default_welcome_intent)**, which is triggered if no messaging-platform-specific Welcome Intent is set.

Therefore, as per the answer in your comments, you already have an intent with the `WELCOME` event (the *Default Welcome Intent*), so the error message you are getting is correct, given that you can only have one `WELCOME` intent per input context.

If you are interested in having different responses for the Welcome Intent, try adding other *Training Phrases* and *Responses*, but you will not be able to create another Intent with the same `WELCOME` event. Alternatively, you may use a different *Input Context*, and in that case you can have multiple Welcome Intents, although you should take into account that the new ones will only be triggered if the given context is met.

Comment: actually I wanted to create this welcome intent so that the bot initiate the conversation first. So how should i use welcome event now?